# Python find row position into matrix

Tags: python, list, indexing, find

I need help with a problem. I have a list like the sample above:

```
list = [[{'bu':'01-DAM-XNXX'}, 45, 60], [{'bu':'02-TAC-MWKKK'}, 80, 120], ...]
```

and I need to find the number of the row depending of the value of the 'bu' key of the dictionary. In this case, for '01-DAM-XNXX it will be 1 and and for '02-TAC-MWKKK' it will be 2 and so on...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What so you mean by row? The nth element of the list is in row n? Or are the first two letter of the value of the dict the row?

Comment: For me a row is each element of the list. For example row1:[{'bu':'01-DAM-XNXX'}, 45, 60]

Comment: And what is the ´01´ at the start of ´01-DAM-XNXX´ when you are looking for the key without the leading numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write them. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it:

```
element = '01-DAM-XNXX'
position = raw_list.index([row for row in raw_list if row[0]['bu'] == element][0])
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest not naming a variable `list` in python. This can lead to all sorts of problems!

Comment: Yeah, I know. Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3

```
search_value = '02-TAC-MWKKK'
ind = (ind for ind, val in enumerate(list) if val[0]['bu'] == search_value).__next__()
```

Python 2

```
search_value = '02-TAC-MWKKK'
ind = (ind for ind, val in enumerate(list) if val[0]['bu'] == search_value).next()
```

Also, as mentioned by @mrCarnivore, please don't name your variable `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an simple function:

```
def searchList(term,searchlist):
    for row in range(len(searchlist)):
        if term in searchlist[row][0]['bu']:
            return row
```